# Benefit of defining model class in angular2+

Tags: angular, typescript

While creating **service** for my domain i realized i can simply implement service using **any** type like this :

```
list(): Observable<any> {
    const url = this.appUrlApi + this.serviceUrlApi;
    return this.http.get(url, { headers: this.header });
  }

add(item: any): Observable<any> {
    const url = this.appUrlApi + this.serviceUrlApi;
    return this.http.post(url, item, { headers: this.header });
  }
```

instead of explicitly mentioning Class like this :

```
list(): Observable<Car[]> {
const url = this.appUrlApi + this.serviceUrlApi;
return this.http.get(url, { headers: this.header });
  }

add(item: Car): Observable<any> {
    const url = this.appUrlApi + this.serviceUrlApi;
    return this.http.post(url, item, { headers: this.header });
  }
```

I know the the second one is correct way and better aproach(while in first way we can save time with less file making and no commitment to properties) but what exactly we benefit from defining model classes and it's **properties** in **Angular** ? 
it was supposed to keep Model as simple as it is possible in MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're effectively asking, "why use strong typing" since this isn't Angular specific.

In a word: scalability.  The bigger the program, the greater likelihood of mistakes.  Types narrow down the what could possibly be going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Easier debugging would be one thing that comes to mind. You'll then know when your double gets filled with a String.